# Probability of orthogonal vectors.

Tags: probability, orthogonality

If I pick two uniformly random vectors over integers
$$(a_1,\dots,a_{n}),(b_1,\dots,b_{n})\in[-m,m]^n\cap\Bbb Z^n$$ what is the probability that
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i=0$$ holds?

Comment: By $[-m,m]$, do you mean an interval in $\Bbb Z$ or an interval in $\Bbb R$ ? In the latter case, the probability is obviously zero.

Comment: @JohnBentin integers.

Answer (score 3):

The orthogonal space of a line given by a vector is a hyperplane, and such a hyperplane has measure $0$ over the ambient space, so I would say such a probability is $0$. Just notice that given a direction, the quantity of other directions that are orthogonal to the first is very tiny compared with all the possible directions.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ the probability is zero if your vectors are independent, because:

\begin{align*}
  P(a_1b_1 = 0) &= P(\{a_1 = 0\} \cup \{b_1 = 0\})\\
  &= P(a_1 = 0) +  P(b_1 = 0) - P(\{a_1 = 0\}\cap \{b_1 = 0\})\\
  &= P(a_1 = 0) +  P(b_1 = 0) - P(a_1 = 0)P(b_1 = 0)\\
  &= 0.
\end{align*}

You could try to do the same with induction for any $n \in \mathbb{N}.$